# Outlook signatures location suddenly changed

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, signature

I have an installation of Outlook 2010 that used to look for signature files in `%appdata%\Microsoft\Signatures`. However, recently it created a folder in `Application Data\Microsoft\Signatures` in the user profile folder and started using that instead.

As I use another application that uses the Outlook signatures in the AppData folder, I need them to be there.

- Why did the location suddenly change to the `Application Data` instead of the `AppData` folder?
- How can I revert to the old settings?

I have checked the registry key that sets the folder to a different location, this is set correctly.

Comment: `/Application Data/...` isn't even a standard directory so it had to have been created by a user.  I would delete the Outlook profile and create a new one to see if the problem is solve.  You should backup the files so you can restore them later.  If you are using IMAP this can be problematic so be sure you understand what you are getting yourself into.

Comment: @Ramhound I know it's not the default location, that's why I'm so puzzled! A new outlook profile has not resolved the issue, unfortunately.

Comment: [How to set Outlook 2010 to use signatures outside of the default signature folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/422523/how-to-set-outlook-2010-to-use-signatures-outside-of-the-default-signature-folde?rq=1) seems to answer your question.

Comment: @Ramhound It would! Except, it does not. This key is set correctly with this user.

Answer (score 0):

It was a wider problem than just Outlook. Somehow, the registry setting `AppData` in

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
```

was set to `%USERPROFILE%\Application Data` instead of `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming`. After fixing this, everything was back in working order. The Application Data folder seems to be the default settings for Windows XP and older. I'm not sure what has caused this change.